# Best practice for making single-use pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, assets

From time to time, we held special events on our site (e.g. discounts or lottery draw). These events each will have a special page (or pages) with very distinct styles/javascripts/images.

These one-time-use pages will be removed once the events are over. Managing the files can get messy as we have to name stylesheets, change the image path inside stylesheets, create corresponding image controller folders, etc.

How to better manage all resources related to the event, so it can be mounted on the main site easily? I have looked into Rails engine, but it seems to require each event to be as one gem, which seems overly complicated for me.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation not so long ago (for user accounts rather than events), we tried managing css and images within the asset file structure with each set contained within a directory named according to the id of the account they were for. This worked fine but meant deploying the whole app for any change in the styles, the number and small nature of change requests on these assets made this process tedious to say the least.

So we have switched to a database driven model. Custom styles are contained in a text field on the account record. Images are hosted on AWS S3 and the stylesheets reference them via absolute urls. We envision one day attaching images to the record using CarrierWave, but for now manually managing the images suffices.